# How to create SQLite DB throw android code?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android application i want to create a SQLite database to store some values.I want to create the the database with auto increment field throw android code.

Please any one help me to do that with some sample code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To create SQLiteDatabase
1.Create a class that implements android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper class
2.Create an object of the above implemented class
3.Call one of the methods getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase() as per your requirement.
4.The above methods returns android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase object,which contains the methods to manage the database

Comment: can anybody please tell me how to access data on mysql server using android application ? please help me its urgent